# How to add specific posts to specific pages in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, wp-query, code

How can I add specific posts to specific pages in WordPress using custom fields and not categories?

Actually, I want to assign a specific custom field value to different posts and show them on different pages on the bases of custom field value?

Comment: And what is the reason for that? What exactly do you want to achieve? And what have you tried already?

Comment: Custom fields are stored as post_meta. Posts can be queried based on meta key and value. Take a look into `WP_Meta_Query` class. This might help you to query posts based on custom field.